# Youtube user delete video callback

Tags: youtube-api

When user delete video is it possible to have callback from youtube website to third party web server ? Any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to hook in callbacks to the YouTube website.  Instead you could build a site with the YouTube apis to delete a video.  The docs for doing video deletions is found here.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete